# DockerFile: Generate SSL certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, dockerfile

I am trying to create a signed ssl certificate when building up the image. But the cert.pfx file was not created. If the container was created and placing the same code to create the certificate, the file generated

```
.


    FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 1445
EXPOSE 44358

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish IdentityServer4WithDocker.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityServer4WithDocker.dll"]


ENV certPassword 1234

# Use opnssl to generate a self signed certificate cert.pfx with password $env:certPassword
RUN openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:1234 -out server.key 2048
RUN openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in server.key -out server.key
RUN openssl req -sha256 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj '/CN=localhost'
RUN openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
RUN openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -certfile server.crt -passout pass:1234

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY IdentityServer4WithDocker/IdentityServer4WithDocker.csproj IdentityServer4WithDocker/
RUN dotnet restore IdentityServer4WithDocker/IdentityServer4WithDocker.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/IdentityServer4WithDocker
RUN dotnet build IdentityServer4WithDocker.csproj -c Release -o /app
```

Comment: Um...don't do that.  In particular the private key is there for anyone who has the image to use and impersonate your site.  This is a good case for injecting the certificate at runtime using a Docker volume.

Comment: Yes I understand... I do this for development only just to trying out the identityserver